# ggplot2 and Shiny: how to scale the size of legend with figure size?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

In ggplot2 the size of elements are specified separately. When the size of figure changes, the elements, for example the legend does not change. This could be a problem in Shiny when the size of output ggplot2 figures changes with browser window. Below is the code of a dummy Shiny app and two output figures at different browser window size. The smaller figure is ugly as part of its legend has been cut off.

Is there a method to scale the legend size with the figure size directly in ggplot2 without pre-saving the figure as an image file for Shiny apps?

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
    br(), br(), br(),
    plotOutput("test", height = "auto")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$test <- renderPlot(
        height = function() {
            0.8 * session$clientData$output_test_width
        },
        expr = {
            aaa <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = cyl)) + 
                geom_point() + 
                theme(legend.position = c(0.9, 0.9))
            print(aaa)
        }
    )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The figure in a larger browser window looks good:
[image]

But in small browser window, the top of the legend does not show up:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a way to anchor the top of the legend so that it doesn't run off the top of the plot area. You just add `legend.justification(0.5, 1)` to the ggplot `theme`. The first value centers the x position of the legend. The second value "top justifies" the y position of the legend. (You can right-justify the legend by changing 0.5 to 1 for the first value, which will keep the legend from running off the right edge of the graph, if that's a problem.) This doesn't solve the relative sizing issue, but the full legend will always be visible and in the same location.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$test <- renderPlot(
    height = function() {
      0.8 * session$clientData$output_test_width
    },
    expr = {
      aaa <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = cyl)) + 
        geom_point() + 
        theme(legend.position = c(0.9, 0.98),
              legend.justification=c(0.5, 1))
      print(aaa)
    }
  )
}
```

Below I've inserted images of what this looks like in "small" and "large" browser windows.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This makes the figure much better.